# Issue with file uploader

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following code in a controller function (this is CI):

```
    if(!empty($_FILES['filename']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) { 
                    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
                    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
                    $config['max_height']  = '768';
                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                    $this->upload->overwrite = true;
                    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('filename')){
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                        var_dump($error);
                        exit;
                     }
                    else {
                        $this->upload->do_upload('filename');
                        $upload_info = $this->upload->data();
                        var_dump($upload_info);
                        exit;
                }
            }
```

This should work, it return no errors, and returns the `$upload_info` array before I `exit();` (exit is here for debugging). The `$upload_info` array suggests that the file has been passed to the correct path on the server. The folder permissions are set to 777 on this folder.

However, the file does not appear on the server! Could anyone suggest what the issue might be here. All the correct libraries have also been loaded.

Comment: what type of file you want to upload and what it is it's size (estimated) ?

Comment: It's 800bytes and a .gif

Comment: What if you remove `exit`?

Comment: No joy if I don't exit() @u_mulder

Comment: @Uchiha what is the 4 in relation to in your condition?

Comment: Sorry my mistake its like as `if($_FILES['filename']['error'] != 4) { `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call for `$this->upload->do_upload('filename')` **twice**.
First time in `if` and then second time in `else`-branch.

You should remove second `$this->upload->do_upload('filename')`.

Final code:

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('filename')){
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    var_dump($error);
    exit;
}
else {
    $upload_info = $this->upload->data();
    var_dump($upload_info);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, still no joy though; the var_dump($upload_info); runs and suggests everything is ok.